# Making progress bar fill multiple times based on the value of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nrjw0Le/4/)

So I have below a code for an html progress bar which fills up when you hit battle. I want to be able to assign a value to a variable so that when you hit battle it will fill the progress bar and battle the monster multiple times = to that value.

```
var auto = 3;

var progress = function(sec){
        var interval = 1000;//milliseconds
        setTimeout(function(){
        sec = sec+25;
            $('#bar').val(sec);
            if(sec <= 100)
                progress(sec);//call self with new value
      else if(sec > 100)
        $('#bar').val(0);
        },interval)
}

$('#battle').click(function() {
    $('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsters').val() + " for 5 damage");
    progress(0);//initialize progress bar
});
```

*Note: this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804513/making-a-progress-bar-fill-multiple-times-based-on-the-value-of-a-variable) because I asked this two days ago and no one answered. So please delete one of these when I get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/6nrjw0Le/6/ , bar fills 3 times then stops for auto = 3

```js
var auto = 3;
var times = 0;
var progress = function(sec){
  var interval = 1000;//milliseconds
  setTimeout(function(){
     sec = sec+25;
   $('#bar').val(sec);
   if(sec <= 100){
    progress(sec);//call self with new value
      } else if(sec > 100){
       if(times===auto-1){
         $('#bar').val(0);
          times = 0;
        } else {
          $('#bar').val(0);
          times++;
          progress(0);
        }        
      }      
  },interval)
}

$('#battle').click(function() {

 $('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsters').val() + " for 5 damage").delay(4500).fadeOut(400);
 progress(0);//initialize progress bar
 
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

progress {
   appearance: none;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 100%;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #81ff14;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  color: #81ff14;
}

select {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #81ff14;
  color: #81ff14;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #81ff14;
  color: #81ff14;
  border-radius: 10%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#dam {
  color: #81ff14;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<progress max="100" value="0" id="bar"></progress>

<select id="monsters">
  <option>Fly</option>
  <option>Mouse</option>
  <option>Rat</option>
  <option>Rabbid Rabbit</option>
  <option>Baby Ent</option>
  <option>Murloc</option>
  <option>Ent</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="battle">Battle!</button>

<p id="dam">

</p>
```

Comment: any suggestion for making the text appear each auto as well? I can't figure out how. I assume it's because I use fadeOut()

Answer (score 1):

Keep calling `progress(sec)` and just reset `sec = 0;` when you reach the end:
Increment an other var, and stop the loop when it reach your auto. You can instead decrements auto if you don't use it anywhere else (auto--).

```js
var auto = 3;
var nb = 0;

var progress = function(sec) {
  var interval = 1000; //milliseconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    sec = sec + 25;
    $('#bar').val(sec);
    if (sec > 100) {
      $('#bar').val(0);
      sec = 0;
      nb++;
    }
    if (nb < auto) progress(sec); //call self with new value
  }, interval)
}

$('#battle').click(function() {
  $('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsters').val() + " for 5 damage").delay(4500).fadeOut(400);
  progress(0); //initialize progress bar
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
progress {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #81ff14;
  border-radius: 5%;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  color: #81ff14;
}
select {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #81ff14;
  color: #81ff14;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #81ff14;
  color: #81ff14;
  border-radius: 10%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#dam {
  color: #81ff14;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress max="100" value="0" id="bar"></progress>

<select id="monsters">
  <option>Fly</option>
  <option>Mouse</option>
  <option>Rat</option>
  <option>Rabbid Rabbit</option>
  <option>Baby Ent</option>
  <option>Murloc</option>
  <option>Ent</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="battle">Battle!</button>

<p id="dam">

</p>
```

Comment: But i want it to continue performing only the amount of times equivalent to var auto. So in my example 3 times, but when the code is completed it will be based on an upgradable number assigned to each user.

Comment: @Shniper Updated the answer